# The pgsql2shp.exe cuts-off text to max 254 characters (varchar(254))

Tags: postgresql, postgis

im using the `pgsql2shp` tool to generate *.shp files from geometries in Postgres. The thing is that I have a description colomn with a lot of text. In the Postgres DB it is of type `text`. But when I use pgsql2shp these columns are cut-off to max 254 characters it makes a varchar(254) of this column.

Any ideas to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more googling and asking around, i found out that the accompanying dbf file with *.shp is based on a dBase IV format. This has a maximum length of a text field = 254 characters. Therefore it cuts the text off.

So I need to find some other solution.

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, this is a limitation of Shapefiles. To get more characters in the output, you need to export to a different format.

You can use [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to convert the spatial data into [several different formats](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html), such as Spatialite, GeoJSON, etc.